# UIUserInterfaceStyle key is not available in Info.plist in Xcode 12, how to disable Dark Mode in Xcode 12 from Info.plist?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode12, ios-darkmode

I am trying to disable Dark Mode support by setting UIUserInterfaceStyle key to Light in Info.plist file but now it's not available in Info.plist in Xcode 12.

[image]

Is it still possible to disable Dark Mode support from Info.plist file for iOS Apps in Xcode 12.

Answer (score 10):

It still exists. Use `Appearance` key.
if you want to find `UIUserInterfaceStyle`, just right click to open menu, and check `Raw Keys & Values`, and you will be able to add `UIUserInterfaceStyle`.

Answer (score 3):

Now You can use Appearance key in info.plist file to Avoid Dark Mode[image]